# Manipulating range of numbers

Tags: java, algorithm

I have following problem: I need an effective program in Java to produce range of -100 to 99999 categorize intervals.

```
Example: A = -10 to 100, B = 200-300...
```

**exceptions:**

- Can not have overlapping ranges.
- Must fill in all numbers.
- According number can not be less than the first

///Edit
I apologize, I was using google lang to comunicate, still using in most part haha
So the code is very similar with what i am doing now in my work, but ofcourse i can't talk in depth haha
I would like something speedy or simpler

```
package com.teste;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

//It is for java 1.4
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {


        //These numbers are provided by user
        Intervalo a = new Intervalo("20", "50");

        //The lowest number will define the first num of interval
        //In this case -20
        Intervalo b = new Intervalo("-20", "150");

        //Invalid interval, in conflict with 'a'
        Intervalo c = new Intervalo("10", "30");

        Intervalo d = new Intervalo("40", "10");//Will throw 2
        Intervalo e = new Intervalo("100","200");
        //Then the range of interval is -20 to 99999
        //But the parameters are dynamic so i did the follow 
        List lista = new ArrayList();

        int menorNum = 99999;

        lista.add(a);
//      lista.add(b);
//      lista.add(c);
//      lista.add(d);
        lista.add(e);



        //Now, I need to validade
        //1-I need to fill all numbers x to 99999 otherwise throw some exception like "there is numbers to categorize..."
        //2-throw exception if getIntervalo2()<getIntervalo1();
        //3-throw exception if one interval are in other interval of numbers

        for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
            Intervalo intervalo = (Intervalo) lista.get(i);

            int num1 = Integer.parseInt(intervalo.getIntervalo1());
            int num2 = Integer.parseInt(intervalo.getIntervalo2());

            if(num2<num1){
                throw new Exception("Exception 2...");
            }
        }

        //finally the lowest number
        for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
            Intervalo intervalo = (Intervalo) lista.get(i);
            if(Integer.parseInt(intervalo.getIntervalo1())<menorNum){
                menorNum = Integer.parseInt(intervalo.getIntervalo1());
            }
        }

        List listaNumeros = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = menorNum; i < 100000; i++) {
            listaNumeros.add(i);
        }
        //I was thinking to make listaNumeros something imutable,
        // copying to new List, but i don't know if it is worth about memory usage
        for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
            Intervalo intervalo = (Intervalo) lista.get(i);

            int num1 = Integer.parseInt(intervalo.getIntervalo1());
            int num2 = Integer.parseInt(intervalo.getIntervalo2());

                int range = num2 - num1;
                int indexOfNum1 =  listaNumeros.indexOf(num1);

            if(indexOfNum1==-1){
                //Throw the exception 3
                throw new Exception("Exception 3... numbers already in use");
            }else{
                for (int k = indexOfNum1; k <=range; k++) {
                    listaNumeros.set(k, null);//The number already used haha...
                }
            }
        }

        //To exception 1
        //Copying again
        List listOfExceptions = new ArrayList();
        String[] interval = new String[2];
        //My idea is, [1,2,3,null,null,4,...], then i know that left to fill [1-3] and [4-99999] 
        for (int i = 0; i < listaNumeros.size(); i++) {
            if(listaNumeros.get(i)!=null&&interval[0]==null){
                interval[0]=listaNumeros.get(i)+"";//I forget what i dided in this line but in my work '+' to concat String are prohibited haha ;
            }
            if(listaNumeros.get(i)==null&&interval[0]!=null){
                interval[1]=listaNumeros.get(i-1)+"";
            }
            if(i==listaNumeros.size()-1){
                interval[1]=listaNumeros.get(i)+"";
            }
            if(interval[0]!=null&&interval[1]!=null){
                listOfExceptions.add(new Exception("Left interval "+interval[0]+" - "+interval[1]));
                interval = new String[2];
            }

        }
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfExceptions.size(); i++) {
            Exception ex = (Exception) listOfExceptions.get(i);
            sb.append(ex.getMessage()).append("\n");
        }
        if(!sb.toString().equals("")){
            throw new Exception(sb.toString());
        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println(":-D");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It's definitely worth showing here.  If nothing else, it explains your question.  Please show us what you've tried if you'd like us to help you.

Comment: Yes, please show the example.  I'm not even sure what you mean by "slow":  slow to code (lots of lines, took you a while to write) or slow to execute.  If slow to execute, explain why that's a concern for you.  (This code will be run millions of times, for instance.)

Comment: You should provide some examples, because your text is gibberish.  Neither  “range of -100 to 99999 categorize intervals” nor  “According number can not be less than the first”  is meaningful.  Also,  “Must fill in all numbers” is ambiguous.

Comment: Why are you parsing the numbers from Strings.  I would just use integers as `int` values.  It would make your code simpler and easier to understand.

Comment: I don't have control about model, i think because they are viewmodel to bind with user input, are generated automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [original revision of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16973192/1) and the supplied code, it seems to me that problem is: Given a range of intervals, validate that these intervals satisfy the 3 conditions. I'm solving this problem below.

I'm not going to give you the code, but here's the idea:

```
sort the intervals
if first.start != -100
  exception - not filling all numbers
iterate through the sorted intervals
  if current.end > current.start
    exception - invalid interval
  if previous.end + 1 < current.start
    exception - not filling all numbers
  if previous.end + 1 > current.start
    exception - overlapping intervals
if last.end != 99999
  exception - not filling all numbers
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment and for having corrected the title. About the idea, yes I had changed to iterate only on list of intervals, but i need to keep the line to inform user "that line are overlapping with lines above in line X", adding this message in some list, sorted by line number of view table, that i have to research about how to sort in java 1.4 haha, I will think more haha but your idea helped so much

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you have already tried this but you could try something like this, I know its not the best way but it should work.

```
for(int i = -100; i< 99999; i++ ){
        if(i>=-10 && i<=100){
            System.out.println("A");
        }
        else if(i>=200&&i<=300){
            System.out.println("B");
        }
        // more else ifs
        else{
            System.out.println("Catch");
        }
    }
```

If that helps at all.